# Как лучше создать вебпак, какое преимущество создавать его в ручную?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Всегда создаю вебпак, командой create-react-app. Также знаю его можно создать в ручную шаг за шагом, вопрос, какой смысл создавать его в ручную? слышала, что create-react-app, добавляет лишние зависимости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Преимущества CRA

- Старт проекта с одной команды

  `npx create-react-app my-app`
- Можно меньше знать о таких утилитах как webpack, babel и других зависимостях сборки и сосредоточится на React-е.
- Только одна зависимость которую нужно поддержать `react-scripts`. Именно он  поддерживает все ваши зависимости сборки. Его легко поддерживать и обновлять с помощью всего одной команды.

  `npm install react-scripts@latest`

#### Недостатки CRA

- Сложно добавить пользовательские конфигурации сборки. Один из способов добавить настраиваемые конфигурации — извлечь приложение через команду `eject`, в таком случае мы теряем преимущество «Только одна зависимость». Другой способ вы можете использовать такие пакеты как  [**customize-cra**](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) или [**react-app-rewired**](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired), но их возможности ограничены.
- Абстрагирует абсолютно все. Важно понимать, что нужно для запуска приложения React. Но из-за преимущества «Только одна зависимость» новичок в React-е может подумать что `react-scripts` является единственной зависимостью, необходимой для запуска React приложений и может не знать что babel, webpack являются ключевыми зависимостями, которые используются под капотом React приложений.
- В CRA входит некоторые npm пакеты которые вам может никогда не понадобится. К примеру поддержка SASS. Если вы используете простой CSS или LESS, то это дополнительная зависимость, которую вы никогда не будете использовать.

#### Преимущества билда с webpack

- Полный контроль над вашим окружением.
- Может легко делать пользовательские настройки, такие как module federation для микрофронтенда. В CRA пока еще такую возможность не добавили, [**PR**](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/12284) все еще висит :)
- Знание того как конфигурировать вебпак это хороший навык, которого часто требуют.

#### Недостатки билда с webpack

- Только вы будете отвечать за обновление и обслуживание вебпака (некоторые версии вебпака и его некоторых плагинов не имеют обратной совместимости или совместимости с будущими версиями).
- Конфигурация может быть пугающим и стать головной болью, особенно если вы пытаетесь научиться писать на React-е.

---

Исходя из опыта скажу следующее:
Если нужно что-то протестировать, чисто для себя и возможностей песочницы мне не хватает, то я всегда выбираю CRA. Если что-то серьезное нужно написать который будет расширяться, то выбираю конфигурацию с вебпаком.

Comment: Sass не нужно ставить дополнительно?

Comment: @OliverPatterson куда именно?

Comment: При `npx create-react-app my-app` уже поддерживается sass "из коробки"? Или нужно его дополнительно устанавливать?

Comment: @OliverPatterson да, SASS устанавливать нужно. Остальное — конфигурация вебпака и sass-loader добавлены под капотом в CRA. Вот тут https://github.com/Nikhil-Kumaran/ejected-react-app/blob/master/package.json можно посмотреть что добавляется в `package.json` после команды `eject`. Как видете там есть sass-loader и конфиг для работы с SASS.

Comment: Понял, спасибо)